# MySQL optimize query for counting scheduled items over time periods

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

In a scheduling application I am working on I am dealing with a fairly complex database schema in order to describe a series of **kids** assigned to **groups** on **timeslots** on certain **dates**. Now in this schema, I want to query the database what the number of scheduled kids are on a certain group for a certain timeslot on a certain range of dates.

## DB Schema

- Timeslot: A timeslot has a certain start and end time (e.g. 13:00 - 18:00). Time can vary in 15-minute steps. In our application we want to schedule a kid on a group for the duration of this timeslot.
- Time slice: For every 15 minutes in a 24-hour period exists a time slice record (96). 15 minutes is the smallest possible planning unit. A timeslot is assigned to each slice covered between its start and end time (for example, timeslot 13:00-18:00 will have a record pointing to time slice [13:00, 13:15, 13:30...17:45]). This makes it possible to count how many kids are 'occupying' the same time slice at any give time and date.
- Kid: A kid is simply the entity being scheduled
- Group: A group is a representation of a physical location with a specific capacity
- GroupAssignment: A group assignment is bound in time. Between date 1 and 2 it could be group A, between date 2 and 3 it could be group B.
- Occupancy: The main scheduling record. This has a timeslot_id, kid_id, start and end date. **note:** a kid is scheduled on the start day and every subsequent 7 days up to the end date.

## DB Schema SQL

The number of records can be roughly derived from the auto_increment value. If not present, I mentioned them manually.

```
CREATE TABLE `group_assignment_caches` (
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_group_assignment_caches_on_occupancy_id` (`occupancy_id`),
  KEY `index_group_assignment_caches_on_group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `index_group_assignment_caches_on_start_and_end` (`start`,`end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/* (~1500 records) */

CREATE TABLE `kids` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `archived` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=592 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `occupancies` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `kid_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeslot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_occupancies_on_kid_id` (`kid_id`),
  KEY `index_occupancies_on_timeslot_id` (`timeslot_id`),
  KEY `index_occupancies_on_start_and_end` (`start`,`end`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2675 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `time_slices` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `index_time_slices_on_start` (`start`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=97 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `timeslot_slices` (
  `timeslot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time_slice_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_timeslot_slices_on_timeslot_id` (`timeslot_id`),
  KEY `index_timeslot_slices_on_time_slice_id` (`time_slice_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/* (~1500 records) */

CREATE TABLE `timeslots` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `start` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` time DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=91 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

## Current solution

So far, I have designed the following query to tie it all together. While it does work, it scales very poorly. Running the query using 1 date, 1 timeslot and 1 group it takes about 50ms. However, with 100 dates this becomes 1000ms and when you start adding groups and timeslots this quickly rises exponentially in the multiple seconds. Ive noticed that the runtime is highly dependent on the **size of the timeslot**. It seems that when a specific timeslot covers more time slices it escalates rapidly in runtime!

```
SELECT subq.date, subq.group_id, subq.timeslot_id, MAX(subq.spots) AS max_spots
FROM (
    SELECT  di.date, 
            ts.start, 
            gac.group_id AS group_id, 
            tss2.timeslot_id AS timeslot_id, 
            COUNT(*) AS spots
    FROM date_intervals di, 
    timeslot_slices tss2,
    occupancies o
        JOIN timeslots t ON o.timeslot_id = t.id
        JOIN group_assignment_caches gac ON o.id = gac.occupancy_id
        JOIN timeslot_slices tss1 ON t.id = tss1.timeslot_id
        JOIN time_slices ts ON tss1.time_slice_id = ts.id
        JOIN kids k ON o.kid_id = k.id
    WHERE di.date BETWEEN gac.start AND gac.end
    AND di.date BETWEEN o.start AND o.end
    AND MOD(DATEDIFF(di.date, o.start),7)=0
    AND k.archived = 0
    AND tss1.time_slice_id = tss2.time_slice_id
    AND gac.group_id IN (3) AND tss2.timeslot_id IN (5)
    GROUP BY ts.start, di.date, group_id, timeslot_id
) subq
GROUP BY subq.date, subq.group_id, subq.timeslot_id
```

Note that running the derived subquery separately takes the same amount of time. This yields 1 record with the number of occupancies for each time slice (15 min) for the given group in the given timeslot. This is great for debugging. Obviously I am only interested in the max number of occupancies for the entire timeslot.

Date_intervals is not described in the schema. This is a temporary table I fill using a REPEAT statement at the beginning of this procedure call. Its only column is 'date' and it's filled with 10-300 dates generally in most situations. The query should be able to handle this.

If I EXPLAIN this query, I get the following results. I am not really sure how to go further from here. The first row about the derived table can be ignored, since executing the subquery takes the same amount of time. The only other table not using an index is date_intervals di which is a small temporary table with 122 records.

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys                                                                                                                          | key                                           | key_len | ref                        | rows | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                                                   | NULL                                          | NULL    | NULL                       | 5124 | Using temporary; Using filesort                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tss2       | ref    | index_timeslot_slices_on_timeslot_id,index_timeslot_slices_on_time_slice_id                                                            | index_timeslot_slices_on_timeslot_id          | 5       |                            |   42 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort   |
|  2 | DERIVED     | ts         | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | ookidoo.tss2.time_slice_id |    1 |                                                |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tss1       | ref    | index_timeslot_slices_on_timeslot_id,index_timeslot_slices_on_time_slice_id                                                            | index_timeslot_slices_on_time_slice_id        | 5       | ookidoo.tss2.time_slice_id |    6 | Using where                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | o          | ref    | PRIMARY,index_occupancies_on_timeslot_id,index_occupancies_on_kid_id,index_occupancies_on_start_and_end                                | index_occupancies_on_timeslot_id              | 5       | ookidoo.tss1.timeslot_id   |    6 | Using where                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | k          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | ookidoo.o.kid_id           |    1 | Using where                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | gac        | ref    | index_group_assignment_caches_on_occupancy_id,index_group_assignment_caches_on_start_and_end,index_group_assignment_caches_on_group_id | index_group_assignment_caches_on_occupancy_id | 5       | ookidoo.o.id               |    1 | Using where                                    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | di         | range  | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                       | 3       | NULL                       |    1 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | t          | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                                                                | PRIMARY                                       | 4       | ookidoo.o.timeslot_id      |    1 | Using where; Using index                       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------+------+------------------------------------------------+
```

## Current results

The above query yields the following results (122 records, abbreviated)

```
date       group_id   timeslot_id max_spots            
+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| date       | group_id | timeslot_id | max_spots |
+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| 2012-08-20 |        3 |           5 |        12 |
| 2012-08-27 |        3 |           5 |        12 |
| 2012-09-03 |        3 |           5 |        12 |
| 2012-09-10 |        3 |           5 |        12 |
+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
| 2014-11-24 |        3 |           5 |        15 |
| 2014-12-01 |        3 |           5 |        15 |
| 2014-12-08 |        3 |           5 |        15 |
| 2014-12-15 |        3 |           5 |        15 |
+------------+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

## Wrapping up

I would like to know a way to either restructure my query or even my database schema in order to make querying this information less time consuming. I can't imagine this being impossible, considering there are relatively so little records present in this database (10-1000's for most tables)

Comment: try a "explain" query and introduce indexes to date_intervals.date

Comment: and introduce indexes to date_intervals.date, occupancies.start, occupancies.end, kids.archived, timeslot_slices.time_slice_id, timeslot_slices.timeslot_id

Comment: Thanks for your quick replies! Was still in the process of adding an EXPLAIN log which didnt make it in the original post. I have already tried most indexing options, though: date_intervals indexes didnt really change anything. Kids.archived is a bolean and not much use for index (low cardinality and needs to use primary ID index anyway). timeslot_slices indexes already present on both fields. occupancy start/end added and this seemed to speed it up a little bit, but I am still stuck around the 1000ms mark for ~100 dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution which is acceptable for my particular use case.

I have created an intermediate or 'cache' table with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `occupancy_caches` (
  `occupancy_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kid_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeslot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `end` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `index_occupancy_caches_on_date_and_client_id` (`date`,`client_id`),
  KEY `index_occupancy_caches_on_date_and_group_id` (`date`,`group_id`),
  KEY `index_occupancy_caches_on_occupancy_id` (`occupancy_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This allowed me to completely eliminate the group_assignment_caches table and no longer did I have to search for dates using calculated columns (MOD(DATEDIFF...)). Also, I only needed a single join on the time slices instead of 2.

The downside, however, is that I now have to create an occupancy_caches record for every week covered by the original occupancies record. In most cases these occupancies describe a 4 year period. This means that for every occupancies record I now have to create 400 (!) records... Since the number of records will only grow linear, correct usage of indexes should keep this from spinning out of control when the system grows.

Time will tell, though...

Answer (score 1):

Any sufficient complex problem can bring a computer to its knees. Actually, it's easy to create a complex problem, and difficult to make a complex problem easy.

Your single query is very complex. It goes over the entire database. Is that necessary? What happens if, for instance, you restrict it to one date? Does it scale better?

Using just a single query to do a complex task is often very efficient, but not always, as you've found out. I often find that the only way to break the exponential time needed to execute the task, is to split it up in multiple steps. One date at a time, for instance. Perhaps you don't always need them all?

In some of those cases I use an intermediate SQLite database that resides in memory. Operations on a small (!) temporary database in memory are very fast. It work like this:

```
$SQLiteDB = new PDO("sqlite::memory:");
$SQLiteDB->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$SQL = "<any valid sqlite query>";
$SQLiteDB->query($SQL);
```

First check that you have the sqlite PHP module installed. Read the manual:

http://www.sqlite.org

When using this you first create tables in your new database and then you populate them with the needed data. You can use prepared statements if you have to copy multiple rows.

The tricky bit is taking apart your single complex query. How you would do that depends on the exact question you want to answer. The art is to limit the amount of data you have to work with. Don't copy the whole database, but make an informed selection.

A big advantage of taking multiple smaller steps is that your code may become much more readable, and understandable. I wouldn't want to be the guy who has to change your SQL query ten years from now because you went on to other things.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate response!

The use-case for my problem is: "Give me the first date which has a free spot for a kid during a certain time period, on a certain weekday in any of these groups". To accomplish this I NEED at least the information from the tables I am grabbing right now. 

Querying only 1 date, then evaluating this in PHP / RoR will produce more overhead than the query itself, I'm afraid.

Maybe if I were to write a loop in a MySQL Stored Proc. which quits as soons as a suitable date is found... At least then I wont have to evaluate _all_ dates in the requested range...

Comment: Date's are just an example, I didn't say you had to use it. There might be something else that's better. Anyway, no matter what you try, It's clear you've made a schema that's as flexible as possible to capture all possible combinations, and more, but with no regard as to how efficient it will be to use. It's probably too flexible! You have to bring in more restrictions. You're looking for a certain type of free timeslot: every seven days, possibly in the same group, etc. That's not reflected in your db schema. IOW: You've modeled the Tetris squares, not the Tetris blocks and their rules.